# Replace string in YAML with stringified JSON

Tags: bash

Say you have a template YAML file:

```
foo:
  bar: {%VARIABLE%}
```

and want the value of `bar` to be a stringified JSON? Ex:

```
foo:
  bar: '{ "hey": "there" }'
```

In my case, the JSON is in a file, so I'm doing this:

```sh
VAR=$(cat my.json)
sed -i '' "s|{%VARIABLE%}|'$VAR'|g" foo.yaml
```

but if you leave the newlines in the JSON, sed complains.

If I use `cat my.json | tr -d '\n'` to remove the newlines, the program ingesting my JSON says the private key in the JSON is invalid.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: What are the exact contents of `my.json`?

Comment: For this example, we'll say the contents are `{ "hey": "there" }`. For my specific case, it's a GCP service account key: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys

Comment: But where are the newlines from then? Does your real file contain newlines? Can you add a representative example JSON file with newlines then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using `perl` instead, which is more robust than `sed`, and allows writing some one-liners as well, such as:

```
VAR=$(<my.json)
perl -i.bak -wpe "s|{%VARIABLE%}|'$VAR'|g" foo.yaml
```

(*tested with the file `my.json` below*)

```
{ "hey" : "there",
  "status" : "ok" }
```

Finally, note that if the `.json` file contains characters such as $ and @ that could have a special meaning in the replacement string, it would be worth it to rely on Perl's quoting operator [`q{}`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators):

```
perl -i.bak -wpe "my \$x=q{$VAR}; s|{%VARIABLE%}|'\$x'|g" foo.yaml
```

or alternatively:

```
perl -i.bak -wpe "my \$x='$VAR'; s|{%VARIABLE%}|'\$x'|g" foo.yaml
```

Comment: @Miles if `my.json` contains some newlines, `perl` will be OK while sed would raise `sed: -e expression #1, char 34: unterminated 's' command`

Comment: This will not work  if there is a single quote in any of the keys or values of the YAML file. It also mangles the multiline example JSON you have to a single line after loading using a YAML parser, which will not affect the semantics of the JSON, but will make it difficult to relate positioning information the interpreting program might give you, back to the original JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is not a YAML file, or even a template YAML file,
as that is not valid YAML: the (flow) mapping start indicator `{` is not followed by a
key-value pair.

What you do have is a *template for a YAML file*, which is using the
jinja2 templating, and there is plug-in for `ruamel.yaml` available to
update exactly that kind of templates (in fact usually a bit more
complex than yours). That plugin converts the template to a valid YAML
file, which can then be loaded, updated and dumped safely using Python.

This has the major advantage in that the value node can be set to be represented as a
*literal style scalar* and that there is no problem with whatever JSON
you throw at it, as your stringified JSON would at least need escaping
of quotes (and possible of backslashes when using double quotes).

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
foo:
  bar: {%VARIABLE%}
"""

json_str = """\
{
  "hey": "there's cake"
}
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='jinja2')
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)

data['foo']['bar'] = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.LiteralScalarString(json_str)
del data['foo'].ca._items['bar']  

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
foo:
  bar: |
    {
      "hey": "there's cake"
    }
```

Normally the non-jinja2 part of the template is edited as YAML, in your case the `del` is needed, 
otherwise the %VARIABLE% would show up in a comment in the ouput.

I on purpose changed the value in the JSON to include a single quote. To include that in your example
output you would need to do:

```
foo:
  bar: '{ "hey": "there''s cake" }'
```

While this might still be doable using non-YAML aware tools like
`sed`, taking care of multi-line JSON with empty lines properly is no
trivial. All these problems go away by inserting the element as a
literal style scalar, but this has to be done using a proper parser,
as that can e.g. take proper action when encountering a first line in
your JSON that is less indented than your second, etc.